# When does unordered_map return -1?

Tags: c++, duplicates, hashtable, unordered-map

I am using an unordered map to check for duplicates in a vector and then erasing it. Sometimes the unordered_map returns -1. I am confused why this happens

```
int removeDuplicates(vector<int>& nums) {

        map<int, int> hash_table;

        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            cout<<nums[i]<<" : "<<hash_table[nums[i]] <<", ";
            hash_table[nums[i]] = hash_table[nums[i]] + 1;

            cout<<nums[i]<<" : "<<hash_table[nums[i]] <<"\n\n";
            if(hash_table[nums[i]] > 1)
            {
                //cout<<"Erasing "<<nums[i]<<"\n";
                nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
                hash_table[nums[i]] = hash_table[nums[i]] - 1;
            }
        }
        cout<<"\n";
        return nums.size();
    }
```

This is the input:

```
[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
```

And this was the stdout:

```
0 : 0, 
0 : 1

0 : 1, 
0 : 2

1 : -1, 
1 : 0

1 : 0, 
1 : 1

2 : 0, 
2 : 1

2 : 1, 
2 : 2

3 : -1, 
3 : 0

4 : 0, 
4 : 1
```

Edit: I initially had the input wrong. It has been edited! (first post on stackoverflow!! i am learning!)

Comment: suggestion, don't use a map here. use a set. `if ( !set.insert( nums[i] ).second ) { *remove from array* }`

Answer (score 4):

This part is the problem:

```
nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
hash_table[nums[i]] = hash_table[nums[i]] - 1;
```

You erase an item from `nums` and *then* use it to decrease value. This means that when there are two zeroes you remove a zero from `nums` and then decrease the value of the number that is at that spot next, which is 1.

First decrease, then erase, so put the lines the other way around.

Also I don’t think the number sequence you gave was correct, it seems it was `0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4`

Comment: That helps a lot! You're right I copy and pasted the wrong input. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

I see couple of problems in your code.

#### Problem 1

The lines

```
nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
hash_table[nums[i]] = hash_table[nums[i]] - 1;
```

need to be swapped. They need to be

```
hash_table[nums[i]] = hash_table[nums[i]] - 1;
nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
```

With the way you have, you are decrementing `hash_table[nums[i]]` after `nums[i]` is erased and it has the value of the item that follows the erased item.

#### Problem 2

You must not increment `i` when you remove an item from `nums`. Otherwise, you are skipping over an element. The `for` loop needs to be:

```
for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); /* i++ */ )
{
   ...

   if(hash_table[nums[i]] > 1)
   {
       hash_table[nums[i]] = hash_table[nums[i]] - 1;
       nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);

       // Don't increment i
   }
   else
   {
       // Increment i
       ++i
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to other answers, I would suggest to use a *set* instead of *map*, which is unnecessarily complicated:

```
int removeDuplicates(std::vector<int>& nums)
{
   std::set<int> hash_table;

   for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); )
   {
      bool inserted;
      std::tie(std::ignore, bool) = hash_table.insert(nums[i]);
      if (!inserted)
         nums.erase(nums.begin() + i);
      else
         i++;
   }

   return nums.size();
}
```